# Is there a word that means "join bodies"?

Tags: word-request, terminology

I am not sure if there's a word for it, but it would make a lot of sense if there was, sometimes in the "acrobatic arts" people do this, so there might be a specific terminology for it, I suspect there's a word for it, but I might be wrong.

For example:

> The cheerleaders ____ to form a big triangle in front of the cheering
>   crowd.

Comment: I'm not sure that there's a term specifically for its use in things like acrobatics, but in your example sentence, ***combined*** would fit just fine. I'm not putting this as an answer because I'm not convinced it's what you're looking for.

Comment: @frbsfok  Are you asking in regard only to acrobatics or in regard to any situation where bodies are joined?

Comment: A word that can be used in any context preferably.

Comment: I'd use *assemble*.

Answer (score -1):

One word that can be used is *gathered*:

> The cheerleaders **gathered** to form a big triangle in front of the cheering crowd.

As a verb, *gathered* means:

> **gather** (*v.*)
>
> - To congregate, or assemble.
>     *People gathered round as he began to tell his story*.
> - To collect from different places; assemble.
> - To cause to come together; convene.
>
> (Sources: [Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/gather), [Wordnik](https://www.wordnik.com/words/gather))